# Data not showing in recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm currently learning Android development and I'm building an app that displays movies from the OMDB api. However when running the app the recyclerview does not show any data. I even tried hardcoding the data and it still shows nothing. I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Here are the files.

movie_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="208dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/movie_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/movie_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_year"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

fragment_movies_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MoviesListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/movie_layout" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

MoviesListFragment.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.FragmentMoviesListBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MoviesListFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_movies_list) {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MoviesListViewModel>()

    private var _binding: FragmentMoviesListBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //View is inflated layout

        _binding = FragmentMoviesListBinding.bind(view)

        val adapter = MoviesListAdapter()

        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
        //Observe the movies livedata
        //Use viewLifecycleOwner instead of this because the UI should stop being updated when the fragment view is destroyed
        viewModel.movies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            //This is the lifecycle of the view of the fragment, not an instance of a fragment
            //It is the paging data itself
            adapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it)

        }
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

MoviesListViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.switchMap
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.paging.cachedIn
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MoviesListViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MoviesRepository): ViewModel() {
    //const of type mutable live data to observe changes for the query
    private val currentQuery = MutableLiveData(DEFAULT_QUERY)

    //results from search requests
    //The switchMap takes a lambda parameter that will be executed when the value of currentQuery changes
    //We get passed a parameter that has the new value of currentQuery
    val movies = currentQuery.switchMap { queryString ->
    repository.getSearchResults(queryString).cachedIn(viewModelScope)//Use viewModelScope to cache in the livedata
    }

    //This function will be called from the fragment when something is typed into the search field
    fun searchMovies(movieTitle: String) {
        currentQuery.value = movieTitle
    }

    companion object {
        //Creating a default value
        private const val DEFAULT_QUERY = "Joker"
    }




}
```

MoviesListAdapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions
import com.example.moviesapp.databinding.MovieLayoutBinding
import com.example.moviesapp.network.Movies

class MoviesListAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Movies, MoviesListAdapter.MoviesListViewHolder>(
    MOVIE_COMPARATOR
) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MoviesListViewHolder {
        val binding = MovieLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return MoviesListViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MoviesListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)

        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }

    }


    class MoviesListViewHolder(private val binding: MovieLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(movie: Movies) {
            binding.apply {
            movieTitle.text = movie.title
            movieYear.text = movie.year
            movieRating.text = movie.rating
                Glide.with(itemView)
                    .load(movie.imageUrl)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_outline_24)
                    .into(movieImage)

            }
        }

    }

    companion object {
        private val MOVIE_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movies>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movies, newItem: Movies) =
                oldItem.id == newItem.id


            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movies, newItem: Movies) =
                oldItem == newItem



        }

    }
}
```

Movies.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import android.os.Parcelable
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Movies(
    @Json(name= "Title") val title: String,
    @Json(name="Year") val year: String,
    @Json(name="Plot") val plot: String,
    @Json(name="imdbRating") val rating: String,
    @Json(name="imdbID") val id: String,
    @Json(name="Actors") val cast: String,
    @Json(name="Writer") val writers: String,
    @Json(name="Director") val director: String,
    @Json(name="Poster") val imageUrl: String,
    ): Parcelable {}
```

MoviesApi.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query


const val OMDB_API_KEY="[mykey]"
interface MoviesApi {


    companion object {


        const val BASE_URL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/"
    }

    @GET("/")
    suspend fun getMovies(
        @Query("t") movieTitle: String,
        @Query("page") page: Int,
        @Query("type") type: String,
        @Query("apikey") key: String = OMDB_API_KEY
    ): MoviesResponse
```

MoviesRepository.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import androidx.paging.Pager
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import androidx.paging.liveData
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
//We use Inject because I own this class, unlike the Retrofit and MoviesApi class
class MoviesRepository @Inject constructor(private val moviesApi: MoviesApi) {
    //This function will be called later on in the ViewModel
fun getSearchResults(movieTitle: String) =
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            //Value at which we want to start dropping items
            maxSize = 50,
            //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesPagingSource(moviesApi, movieTitle)}
    //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
    ).liveData

}
```

MoviesPagingSource.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import androidx.paging.PagingSource
import androidx.paging.PagingState

//Declare the const outside of class because it is not related to the class
private const val MOVIES_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1


class MoviesPagingSource(
    private val moviesApi: MoviesApi,
    private val movieTitle: String
): PagingSource<Int, Movies>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Movies> {
       return try {
            val position = params.key ?: MOVIES_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
            val response = moviesApi.getMovies(movieTitle, position, "movie")
             LoadResult.Page(
                //Data you want to load
                data = response.results,
                //Calculate the number of the previous and next page
                prevKey = if (position == MOVIES_STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else position - 1,
                nextKey = if (response.results.isEmpty()) null else position + 1

            )
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
             LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Movies>): Int? {
        //Used for subsequent refresh calls to PagingSource.load()
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }


    }

}
```

MoviesResponse.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

data class MoviesResponse(
    val results: List<Movies>
)
```

MoviesRepository.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.network

import androidx.paging.Pager
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import androidx.paging.liveData
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
//We use Inject because I own this class, unlike the Retrofit and MoviesApi class
class MoviesRepository @Inject constructor(private val moviesApi: MoviesApi) {
    //This function will be called later on in the ViewModel
fun getSearchResults(movieTitle: String) =
    Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            //Value at which we want to start dropping items
            maxSize = 50,
            //Disabling placeholders for objects that haven't been loaded yet
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {MoviesPagingSource(moviesApi, movieTitle)}
    //Turn this pager into a stream of paging data to get live updates
    ).liveData

}
```

Comment: How did you start debugging? Did you check if the API is called? If the API is returning something? If the repository method is called? If the observe callback of the LiveData is called? Give us some insights, do debugging, that's what development is about.

Comment: I tried hardcoding the strings and it didn't work. So the problem is not with the API, probably something related to the fragment and/or viewmodel but I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not calling this method `searchMovies` though.

```
//This function will be called from the fragment when something is typed into the search field
fun searchMovies(movieTitle: String) {
    currentQuery.value = movieTitle
}
```

If you called it somewhere and didn't add the code for it, please edit your question with that part and I'll try to help :)

Comment: No I didn't but I even tried to hardcode the strings and it still didn't show up so I don't think this function is the problem

Comment: ok, then can you edit your question and add the code for your `MoviesPagingSource` as well?

Comment: Just added the file

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `"/"` from your `@GET` since you have already added in baseUrl (which is the part of baseUrl). This is how this api is designed, you have added `"/"` in your `@GET` now your baseUrl is like this: 
`http://www.omdbapi.com//`
see that? extra `/` at the end, this is the cause of not showing data.

Comment: @Ahmadddd4 what does it says now?

Comment: put the ``?`` in your ``@GET`` instead ``/``

Comment: It doesn't say anything. Also I'm 100% it's not the api since I hardcoded the string's texts and nothing shows. I can see the scroll shadow but I don't see my cardview

Comment: it could be the api problem as far as i could understand not showing the data means you must done something wrong with your api end points if everything else seems fine, did you try ``?`` instead ``/`` and please post your `MovieResponse` class

Comment: In the design view of the layouts I can see the cardview and the hardcoded strings just fine but when I run the app i dont see anything, I just get the scroll shadow when I try scrolling

Comment: Post Your ``MovieResponse`` class

Comment: Just added the files

Comment: why did u model it like so? are your following some sort of documentation or you did it by yourself? and why you getting the list of movie when you are using ``title`` there is no pagination or page option available when using ``title`` as per website, you will getting single movie result not list as per documentation. now there are two ways you can try out either get single result by using ``Movies`` rather than using ``MovieResponse`` or change your api, cause you have confused two different end points and query params

Comment: There is a "t" parameter though and I gave that a kotlin variable of movieTitle in the Movies.kt class. Also there is no option to get a list of all movies from that api for some reason. Shouldn't there be a MoviesResponse class to display the list of Movies though?

Comment: no, cause this is how the api is designed even though you can't make nested model for single result like ``MovieResponse(val movie: Movies)`` this is also be considered as wrong. when you search via ``Title`` it gives single result or single object for specific movie. and you also have ``page`` query in your api and this is also problem cause in actual url there is no page option for single result.

Comment: Okay I will change the api and get back to you. But the thing is as I said I already tried giving the textviews a text attribute and still nothing showed

Comment: you need to change your model as well for single result and query params also according to documentation.

Comment: I didn't quite get that. The MoviesResponse.kt should be changed?

Comment: if you wanna get the single result just use ``Movie`` in your api and follow query params as per documentation. and if you wanna get the list of data then you should know how api is designed for lists cause in given link or website i could see for single result for free. just make sure whatever you are doing your query params and end point must be as per documentation and models are modeled as per response no need to additional nesting if its not required.